Exercise about convex hull and weak convegence
Suposse $X$ is a normed space, $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence in $X$, $x \in X$ such that $x_k \underset{weakly}{\rightarrow} x$.
Let $co$ denote the convex hull.
Show that, there exists $y_k \in co\{x_1,...,x_k\}$ such that $||y_k-x|| \rightarrow 0.$
Hint:
Let E:=$co\{x_1,...,x_k\}$, denote $\overline{E}$ to be the closure of $E$
and denote $\overline{E_w}$ to be the weak-closure of $E$.
Show that $\overline{E_w}=\overline{E}$.
My attempt:
The direction $\overline{E} \subseteq \overline{E_w}$ follows by the fact that the weak topology is coarser than the norm-topology.
(For details see here:
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Topological_Closure_in_Coarser_Topology_is_Larger)
The other direction $\overline{E_w} \subseteq \overline{E}$, follows by applying the Hahn-Banach Separation Theorem (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Hahn-Banach_Separation_Theorem/Normed_Vector_Space/Real_Case/Compact_Convex_Set_and_Closed_Convex_Set).
Now I know that $\overline{E_w}=\overline{E}$. But I don't see how to continue.

The limit point $x$ must lie in the weak closure of $E$ and this it's norm closure. Now any point of the (norm) closure of $E$ can be approximated by a sequence in $E$

$x_k \rightarrow_w x$, therefore $x$ must lie in the weak closure $\bar E_w$.
As such $x$ must also lie in the strong closure $\bar E$. Unlike in the weak topology, in the norm topology closedness and sequential closedness are equivalent.
Now for every neighbourhood $U_x$ of $x$ there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that the open ball $B_\epsilon(x)$ is a subset of $U_x$ and contains an element of $E$.
